# Python Beautifulsoup- get text from a tag and from the tag immediately below it

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a long file that reuses tags a lot. I need the text from an arbitrary number of two of the tag types (though I do not need the text from every tag of that type).

Here is a snippet of the xml file:

```
<key>category</key>
<string>Utilities</string>
<key>description</key>
<string></string>
<key>developer</key>
<string></string>
<key>display_name</key>
<string>PaperCut Client</string>
<key>icon_hash</key>
<string>0db77f1181a63838123e5b25607be0b9b7e32432d11ec3f370ddde1a7807f3fc</string>
<key>installer_item_hash</key>
<string>ebe1f3093bf20f0c6524e79005b37f932dcfe0166a0d740d985450e7a55f9ca0</string>
<key>installer_item_location</key>
<string>PCClient-13.5.dmg</string>
<key>installer_item_size</key>
<integer>45941</integer>
<key>installer_type</key>
<string>copy_from_dmg</string>
<key>installs</key>
```

What I need to extract is the text of a key tag and then the string tag immediately following it:

```
<key>'identifier'</key>
<string>'desired text'</string>
```

I can return all the display_name tags with:

```
soup.findAll('key', string="display_name")
```

But this returns the tag  **and** the string 'display_name'. I only need 'display_name', and the text from the following tag (the text from the 'string' tag, e.g. 'PaperCut Client'). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xml = '''
<key>category</key>
<string>Utilities</string>
<key>description</key>
<string></string>
<key>developer</key>
<string></string>
<key>display_name</key>
<string>PaperCut Client</string>
<key>icon_hash</key>
<string>0db77f1181a63838123e5b25607be0b9b7e32432d11ec3f370ddde1a7807f3fc</string>
<key>installer_item_hash</key>
<string>ebe1f3093bf20f0c6524e79005b37f932dcfe0166a0d740d985450e7a55f9ca0</string>
<key>installer_item_location</key>
<string>PCClient-13.5.dmg</string>
<key>installer_item_size</key>
<integer>45941</integer>
<key>installer_type</key>
<string>copy_from_dmg</string>
<key>installs</key>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml')
keys = soup.find_all('key', string='display_name')
for key in keys:
    string = key.next_sibling.next_sibling
    print(key.text)
    print(string.text)
```

out:

```
display_name
PaperCut Client
```

Answer (score 0):

If `key` and `string` always come in pairs and stay in same order(which I suppose it should be, or the whole xml file would end up in chaos), you could do this:

```
for key_tag, string_tag in zip(soup.find_all('key'), soup.find_all('string')):
    print key_tag.text, string_tag.text
```

Comment: Thanks. This line of code is useful; however, since there are so many string tags, this overselects string tags' text, instead of targeting just the 'display_name' string.